# How to start memory scrubbing manually

Tags: memory, memtest86+, ecc, memtest

ECC memory scrubbing is usually a passive process that happens in the background. But I was wondering if I can start it by hand and monitor its progress and maybe test specific address ranges?

Regards

Comment: Memory is checked at every read from the processor, so basically a product like memtest86 will do that.

Comment: I would like to do it while the server is running, memtest can only be done offline, right? (And I cannot run a virtual machine on that system in order to run memtest inside that vm.)

Comment: Run a program that allocated all available memory and fill it with some data?

Comment: Configure the kernel so you can read from `/dev/mem` (see `man 4 mem`, investigate `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`). Then use `cat /dev/mem >/dev/null` (or `pv`, or `dd`, or whatever) to read all the memory or (with a tool that supports offset+size) its fragment.

Comment: Okay, I've tried creating an almost 100% sized RAM disk, filled it with /dev/urandom and read the file afterwards. This did not trigger the correctable error, i was looking for. Furthermore I tried a tool called LiME. This seems to be something similar like the mentioned CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM approach, but this did not trigger the mce message either. What am i missing at this point?